# Help on theorem environment

Tags: xetex, environments, theorems, right-to-left

Could someone help me create these (theorem) environments with latex, with support for RTL language please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Show what you have tried.